# Do handstand push-ups hit all the three shoulder heads?

Tags: muscle, shoulders, calisthenics, muscle-imbalance

I started working out with calisthenics recently, and I want to workout my shoulders using only hand stand push-ups. Will that be enough to have good looking strong shoulders?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't hit all three shoulder heads (assuming you mean the anterior, lateral and posterior deltoids.) [Breakdown of handstand push-ups.](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BWHandstandPressBench.html)

Mechanically I don't see how you can work all of the shoulder muscles unless you can encounter resistance coming from the wide range of angles the shoulder can direct force to.  A gymnast routine on the rings would probably do it, but does that count as a single exercise?

You should be able to find a small repertoire of [shoulder exercises](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ShouldWt.html) that hit all the muscle heads and fit in with your calisthenics routine.  I cannot speak to how visible the development would be.

Comment: Mechanically, you cannot. You can get Ant/Lat, Lat/Post, or individual... but not all 3. I will accept the argument of doing a concentric movement that hits Ant/lat and has an eccentric lengthening that hits Lat/Post or just post.